# Counting the occurence of Sundays in a given date range without quering a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of Sundays occurring in a given date range using MySQL...
My problem is the dates given is not in a table...all I want is to let SQL compute it without any query..for example: SELECT DATEDIFF(date1,date2); which of course doesn't need any tables to query.
Is it possible?

Comment: Why are you doing it in the database at all if you're not accessing any data?

Comment: cause I'm using a company made CGI that makes use of sql and javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's posible.

Suppose that your date1 is greater than date2.

so,

```
first_sunday = DATE_ADD(@date2, interval (8 - DAYOFWEEK(@date2)) mod 7 DAY)
```

is the sunday next to @date2, if @date2 is sunday, first_sunday is @date2

```
last_sunday = DATE_ADD(@date1, interval 8 - DAYOFWEEK(@date1) DAY)
```

is the sunday next to @date1 even where @date1 is sunday or not, we will not count last_sunday

```
sunday_count = FLOOR(DATEDIFF(last_sunday, first_sunday)/7)
```

will return your sunday amount from date2 to date1.

If you want an only one query, this is it:

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DATE_ADD(@date1, interval 8 - DAYOFWEEK(@date1) DAY), DATE_ADD(@date2, interval (8 - DAYOFWEEK(@date2)) mod 7 DAY))/7)
```